# Started early because I had some lectures to attend later on. OR Started early because I have some lectures to attend later on

Tags: grammar, tenses, sentence, speech, indirect-speech

Which one of the following sentences is correct?

**I started** early because **I had** some lectures to attend later on.

OR

**I started** early because **I have** some lectures to attend later on.

Comment: They mean different things. Are the lectures in the future (2nd sentence) or the past (1st sentence)?

Comment: Both are grammatical.

Comment: Lectures are in the future.

Comment: In that case, as @StuartF has told you, it's the second version. This question is more suited to https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions